# How to get the size of a Generic param that extends Struct(ffi)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am a beginner of Dart and I encounter this problem recently, here is the code:

```
class Test<T extends Struct> {
  int sizeOfT() {
     return sizeOf<T>();
  }
}
```

And I get this error:

`The type arguments to 'sizeOf' must be known at compile time, so they can't be type parameters.`

I found that the generic in Dart is dynamic(Type was determained at runtime). I think that is the root cause, but how can I make it right?

I have read the document about Struct class in Dart, still cannot solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code, I hope it helps you.

```
import 'dart:ffi';

class Test<T extends Struct> {
  int sizeOfT() {
    return sizeOfTstruct<T>();
  }

  static int sizeOfTstruct<T extends Struct>() {
    return sizeOf<T>();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It also doesn't not work .